# Symstore does not delete associated folders

Tags: c++, powershell, symstore

I use a symbol store on a network drive to collect debug symbols for our application.  The symbols are used while debugging a crash dump file that has been loaded into Visual Studio.  I have Powershell scripts in place that manage deleting ‘old’ versions of symbols.  Or, so, I thought.
Recently, while working on another script, I noticed that using [symstore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681417(v=vs.85).aspx) to delete symbols doesn’t actually delete anything.  When I use symstore to delete symbols I see a “0000000161.deleted” file in 000Admin folder for example.  This file contains entries for the associated debug symbols.  It contains entries like:

```
"Aggregat.pdb\B4E7044117F0469CB321E9FA9003E4CA5","C:\temp\pdbs\1823\Aggregat.pdb"
```

The first entry above is the folder for the associated debug symbols for the ‘Aggregat’ module.  I would expect that when I delete symbols using the transaction ID, that the corresponding folders (ie. B4E7044117F0469CB321E9FA9003E4CA5) would also be removed.  It appears like that’s not the case.

Is my assumption correct?  Am I responsible for the full cleanup of the symbols store structure?